# Where to announce or release 'opensource' photos

Tags: open-source, sharing

There are many questions on where to release photos for sale or copyright information.  I have taken some photos that are not world class, but I think useful for some people.  I have been working on a section on my website with resources for people.  So far I have been creating tutorials and releasing 3d Models.  For tutorials it is easy for others to find because the content is written and easily searchable.  For models, releasing them on thingiverse works somewhat well.

Is there a common announcement board or site that I can let others know about the free photos and the repository that I am making?

Answer (score 5):

I use [CC search](http://search.creativecommons.org) to find creative commons images. It's a meta-search engine and it searches sites like Flickr and Wikimedia Commons. You could upload your work to one of the searched sites, indicate under what creative commons licence the images fall and describe them as much as possible (keywords, location).

Comment: indeed. My Wikimedia photos are where I get usage/attribution requests the most.

Answer (score 1):

You can submit photos to free stock photo libraries. www.sxc.hu (changed to www.freeimages.com) was I think bought by iStockPhoto, but looks like the group might have been taken over by Getty Images. If you're happy for your images to be used without charging people, this could be a good way of getting your images seen

Answer (score -2):

[creativecommons.org](http://creativecommons.org/) - see the [Photography](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/Photography) section of the [case study wiki](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/Case_Studies).

More importantly though, make sure you [clearly understand](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/114016) how to get your [marked](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/Marking_your_work_with_a_CC_license) images noted by the major search engines and know the importance of [SEO gold](http://platowebdesign.com/articles/seo-tips-and-tricks-worth-1k-or-more/).

Reading list:

[A User's Opinion](http://offbeatempire.com/2013/04/flickr),
[Top ranked social media sites](http://www.ebizmba.com/articles/social-networking-websites),
[Authorship Markup Tips](https://blog.kissmetrics.com/google-authorship/)